# Currently (02/09/2019), how many entry guards does Tor choose and for how long are they maintained?

Tags: guard-node

Two years ago, an identical question was done ([Currently, how many entry guards does Tor choose and for how long are they maintained?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/14269/currently-how-many-entry-guards-does-tor-choose-and-for-how-long-are-they-maint)). Now (02/09/2019) I ask the same, because I am seeking for an updated answer:

In the version 0.4.1.5, how many 'entry guards' are chosen and for how long are they maintained?